# jQuery and parallel events

Tags: jquery, events, click, bind, unbind

let's take a look at my question! I have a HTML page, with 2 DIVs. Both of these are linked to a jQuery function triggered on click events. So we have div1 and div2. Here we have some code:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
....
<script>
   $('#div1').click(function(){
       $('#div1').animate({some animations...},1000);
   });
   $('#div2').click(function(){
       $('#div2').animate({something else...},1000);
   });
</script>
```

Ok, my problem is that if an user try to click the div1, div1 have to do animation and it will take some time... but if during this animation the user try to click div2, this click doesn't have to be triggered until the div1 animation is finished. The script i posted is just a very short version of mine, and i cannot modify the structure of those functions.
I tryied using *bind/unbind* but I'm not able to let the divX wait until the other animation stops, 'cause *bind function* autotrigger the event i attach to the element. Can you help me?

EDIT: just to be sure everyone can understand, suppose that in my example we have 5 divs, each one with a different functions triggered on click event. if i click div1, all the other divs must be disabled during the execution of the animation triggered by div1, after the animation is complete they can be enabled on click event again.... in order to be sure that ,if i click on div1, then until the anim is complete i can click all the other divs but no event must be triggered.

Comment: Are you saying you want div1 to finish animating before div2 starts animating? Maybe the jQuery.queue() function will help?  http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: re: edit - so you want the clicks completely disabled, not just queued up?

Comment: just want to disable the click event during an animation, then re-enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one animation wait for another to complete by using deferred objects:

```
$('#div2').click(function() {
    $('#div1').promise().done(function() {
        $('#div2').animate(...);
    });
});
```

The `.promise().done(...)` will only start the inner callback when any existing animations on `#div1` have completed.  If there are none, it'll proceed immediately.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/NjCf4/

Alternatively, you can use `.queue`:

```
$('#div1').queue(function(next) {
    $('#div2').animate(...);
    next();
});
```

The latter code will queue the animation of `#div2` on the end of the current queue for `#div1`.  However if subsequent additional animations get queued on `#div1` they'll still happen later.

The deferred method is probably better because 1) it allows you to wait on an arbitrary set of elements, and 2) it specifically waits until all animations are done, rather than dropping a new action into the queue.

Comment: your example seems legit but it suppose that an animation must be triggered after another one for sure...and in my opinion this is not true. just imagine the example i made before, if the user click on div1 , the first animation starts, but if the user doesn't trigger the second animation your example wont work. i don't know if an user will click on each div, i just don't want to create parallel execution of different animations. if i click on div1, the div2 must not work until the div1 animation is complete, just this.

Comment: @alfa that's precisely what this code does.  It prevents div2 from animating until after the animations on div1 *if any* have completed.

Comment: mmhh...maybe i misunderstood, but i think u're supposing that i want to trigger the event of div2 after the event of div1....and that's not what i'm searching for. if i misunderstood, excuse me! btw, i'm trying your method right now

Comment: @alfa no, the code above is still dependent on you clicking an element - it's what would be _inside_ the click handler.  See the fiddle for the complete example.  **EDIT** I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: so, if i have 3 or more divs instead of 2...i can make nested promise().done() to handle my problem, right?

Comment: @alfa no, you just list all of those divs in `$('#div1,#div2')` etc, or better yet, use a class - `$('.mydivs').not(this).promise()...`

Comment: ok, i tryed, but it doesn't work. still produce parallel animations if i click all the divs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are firing functions that take a while (an animation could take a second or more while it's executed), and while this is executed the process is blocked.

Nicholas C. Zakas recommends in his book "High Performance Javascript" to encapsulate long processing operations in small slices of time to avoid those operations from blocking the rest of the execution.

The main idea is to use timers to divide each operation that takes more than 50ms. I'll see if I can post here an example later.

Comment: actually jQuery animations don't block anything.  If they did the OP wouldn't have the problem he does.

Comment: Oh... I see... I've understood the opposite, that he wanted their animation to start just when the div is clicked despite of there is any other animation executing.

Answer (score 0):

By a flag you can find that animation is running or not.

```
flag = false;
$("#div1").click(function() {
  flag = true;
  $( "#anim1" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25}, 1000, function() {
    flag = false;
  });
});
```